# Create column based on another column value, based on assigning value to sets of string values from the input column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My problem seems like it must have a simple solution, but I am unable to solve it. I've tried `.loc` , `np.where` and `df.apply`.

```
#input          
datetime        dty dtx     status
2018-09-16 04:38:17 0.0 0.099854    F-On
2018-09-16 04:38:18 0.0 0.100098    F-On
2018-09-16 04:38:19 0.0 0.000000    S-On
2018-09-16 04:38:20 0.0 0.100098    F-On
2018-09-16 04:38:21 0.0 0.100098    circ    
2018-09-16 04:38:22 0.0 0.100098    circInS
2018-09-16 04:38:21 0.0 0.100098    TH
2018-09-16 04:38:21 0.0 0.100098    R
2018-09-16 04:38:21 0.0 0.100098    S
```

'mapping' exists from domain -

```
    (F-On,S-On) becomes 'On'
    (circ,TH,circInS) becomes 'fooON'
    (R) stays 'R'
    (S) stays 'S'

#expected ouput         
datetime        dty dtx     status grouped_status               
2018-09-16 04:38:17 0.0 0.099854    F-On    On
2018-09-16 04:38:18 0.0 0.100098    F-On    On
2018-09-16 04:38:19 0.0 0.000000    S-On    On
2018-09-16 04:38:20 0.0 0.100098    F-On    On
2018-09-16 04:38:21 0.0 0.100098    circ    fooON
2018-09-16 04:38:22 0.0 0.100098    circInS fooON
2018-09-16 04:38:21 0.0 0.100098    TH  fooON
2018-09-16 04:38:21 0.0 0.100098    R   R
2018-09-16 04:38:21 0.0 0.100098    S   S
```

> `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
>   a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

[I understand the code below is comparing an array to a single value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o);
Which is ambigious, hence it fails. To compare row wise I tried using `df.apply`, but it is not giving desired output.

How do I make all three of the methods below work if possible, and which is the best way for a row-wise operation?

```
#using np.where
df['grouped_status'] = np.where(df['status'] in ('circ','TH','circInS'), 'fooON', df['status'])

#using df.loc
df.loc[df['status'] in ('circ','TH','circInS'),['status']] = 'fooON'
df['grouped_status'] = df['status']

#function for df.apply
def group_status_fn (row):  

    val = ""

    if row['grouped_status'] in ('F-On','B-On','S-On'):
        row['grouped_status'] = 'On'
    elif row['grouped_status'] in (circ,TH,circInS):
        row['grouped_status'] = fooON

    elif row['grouped_status'] == 'R':
        val = 'R'
    elif row['grouped_status'] == 'S':
        val = 'S'

    return val

#using df.apply
df["grouped_status2"]=df.apply(group_status_fn, axis = 1)

#out - output column half empty
datetime        dHD     status grouped_status grouped_status2               

2018-09-16 04:38:35 0.000000    F-On    F-On    
2018-09-16 04:38:36 0.000000    F-On    F-On    
2018-09-16 04:38:37 0.000000    S-On    S-On    
2018-09-16 04:38:38 0.000000    S-On    S-On    
2018-09-16 04:38:39 0.000000    R   R   R
2018-09-16 04:38:40 0.099854    R   R   R
2018-09-16 04:38:41 0.100098    R   R   R
2018-09-16 04:38:42 0.000000    R   R   R
2018-09-16 04:38:43 0.000000    R   R   R
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
lookup = {'F-On' : 'On', 'S-On' : 'On', 'circ':'fooON', 'TH':'fooON', 'circInS':'fooON', 'R':'R', 'S':'S'}
df['grouped_status'] = df.status.map(lookup)
```

**Output**

```
            datetime  dty       dtx   status grouped_status
2018-09-16  04:38:17  0.0  0.099854     F-On             On
2018-09-16  04:38:18  0.0  0.100098     F-On             On
2018-09-16  04:38:19  0.0  0.000000     S-On             On
2018-09-16  04:38:20  0.0  0.100098     F-On             On
2018-09-16  04:38:21  0.0  0.100098     circ          fooON
2018-09-16  04:38:22  0.0  0.100098  circInS          fooON
2018-09-16  04:38:21  0.0  0.100098       TH          fooON
2018-09-16  04:38:21  0.0  0.100098        R              R
2018-09-16  04:38:21  0.0  0.100098        S              S
```